# 2D game motion using accelerometer

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics

I'm trying to make a smooth motion for my game (LIBGDX project), my plans include accelerometer and basic physics movement but still i'm just a newbie and don't know/want to try box2d.

```
private Vector2 velocity,acceleration,current;

    velocity=new Vector2(0,0);
    current=new Vector2(0,0);
    acceleration=new Vector2(0,0);
```

bascially i store velocity,acceleration and tilt in a Vector2;

```
    current.x=initialX - Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    current.y=initialY - Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
    float dt=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Here i calculate current rotation based on initial value that accelerometer gave

```
if (current.x<1 && ship.shipbounds.getX() >= 0) acceleration.add(0.2f,0);
if (current.x>1 && ship.shipbounds.getX()<=1080-ship.shipbounds.getWidth()) acceleration.add(-0.2f,0);
if (current.y<1) acceleration.add(0, 0.2f);
if (current.y>1) acceleration.add(0,-0.2f);
       velocity.add(acceleration.x*dt,0);
        ship.shipbounds.setPosition(ship.shipbounds.x + velocity.x * dt, ship.shipbounds.y + velocity.y * dt);
```

That's the part of code that is not working(i guess):when ship should be staying still it moves to top-right and if i try to make it go button-left it goes a bit but after that its top-right speed increases making it uncontrollable

Comment: if shipbounds.y has a starting value of anything other than 0 then when you do `ship.shipbounds.y + velocity.y * dt` dt will bring it up or down depending on your delta time value.  you probably shouldnt be calculating dt in twice. so i would take the `* dt` out of `ship.shipbounds.setPosition(ship.shipbounds.x + velocity.x * dt, ship.shipbounds.y + velocity.y * dt);` let me know if this works and ill make an answer! I also noticed your not using acceleration.y but you are calculateing it. But im guessing its for later use?

Comment: or add parens around your calculations so it will ensure it is calculating dt before it adds it to your ships positiion `ship.shipbounds.setPosition(ship.shipbounds.x + (velocity.x * dt), ship.shipbounds.y + (velocity.y * dt));`

Comment: @Rosenumber14 thats right i have left acceleration.y for later, just testing for x now. Also i make changes to code as you said but it stills goes to right

Comment: Its going to the right when you dont tilt it, correct? so current.x should be 0 then accesseration.x should be 0 so 0*dt = 0 so velocity.x should be 0 if ship starting position was 15 then `ship.shipbounds.x (15) + (velocity.x(0) * dt) = 15` so it shouldnt move...

Comment: Only other thing i can advise would be to add debug logging (or breakpoint if you can), check all the variables, and make sure all the numbers add up like they should.